# Missing Required Property: The og:url property is required, but not present

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a simple page with like button inside in my facebook app
when i test my page on the facebook debugger, i got this messages:

Missing Required Property:  The og:url property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property:  The og:type property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property:  The og:title property is required, but not present.

but i declared all the meta tags in my page, what am i missing?

this is my page html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="ttt" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://apps.facebook.com/yositestmylife/Facebook/TEST.aspx" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://apps.facebook.com/yositestmylife/Media/Images/credit.png" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="sss" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="600018507" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>  
    <script>        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=306398689381800";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    TEST
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://apps.facebook.com/yositestmylife/Facebook/TEST.aspx"
        data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement achievements in you application ?

If you are going to implement only like button functionality, then there is no need for any meta tags to be included in your page.

And if you are trying to implement Facebook Achievements to your application then please refer to [Achievements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to implement achievements in my application but without success

what's wrong with my html?

Comment: Try to create individual pages for all the achievements. Don't put any other code apart from achievement tags.. e.g.

<meta property="og:title" content="ttt" />
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://apps.facebook.com/yositestmylife/Facebook/TEST.aspx" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://apps.facebook.com/yositestmylife/Media/Images/credit.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="sss" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="600018507" />

Comment: And also let me know if you are not able to create the achievements from the back-end that is provided by Facebook from the settings page.